# how to make padding between textfield

Tags: flutter, textfield

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdyLa.png)i want make padding betwenn this

Container(

```
                  child: Column(
                    children: \<Widget\>\[
                      
                      //  Radio(value: 1, groupValue: 'Null', onChanged: (index) {}),
                      // Expanded(
                      //   child: Text('A domicile'),
                      // ),
                      // Radio(value: 1, groupValue: 'Null', onChanged: (index) {}),
                      // Expanded(
                      //   child: Text('En consigne'),
                      // ),

                      TextField(
                        
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          
                          
                          labelText: '  Ref Expedéteur',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                           
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3, color: const Color(0xffff4848)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: '  Nombre de colis',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3, color: const Color(0xffff4848)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: '  Poids',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              width: 3,
                              color: const Color(0xffff4848),
                            ),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: '  Taille de colis',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 2,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 2, color: const Color(0xffff4848)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 2,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),

                      // Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      // child:Column(
                      //   children: \[
                      //        Radio(value: 1, groupValue: 'Null', onChanged: (index) {}),
                      //   Expanded(
                      //   child: Text('Paye'),
                      // ),
                      //   \],
                      // ),
                      // ),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: '  Ref Expedéteur',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 5, 5),
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3, color: const Color(0xffff4848)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: '  Nombre de colis',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3, color: const Color(0xffff4848)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: '  Poids',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3, color: const Color(0xffff4848)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: '  Taille de colis',
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                            fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
                          ),
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3, color: const Color(0xffff4848)),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(40),
                            ),
                          ),
                          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                width: 3,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

this is my code its work in side padding but i want padding inside text field
im begginner in flutter

this is my code its work in side padding but i want padding inside text field  im begginner in flutter

this is my code its work in side padding but i want padding inside text field  im begginner in flutter

```
                    \],
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by padding inside TextField? The padding inside the TextFields looks right to me, maybe you were trying to say that you want to add some kind of spacing between the TextFields? If that's the case, you have multiple options, I find this one the simplest one:

```
TextField(...)
SizedBox(height: 12)
TextField(...)
SizedBox(height: 12)
...
```

You get the idea...

I would also recommend you to extract those TextField widgets into a private widget that receives X number of parameters, this way you avoid repeating so much code and everything would look cleaner and more readable.

Something like:

```
class _CustomTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  const _CustomTextField({
    Key? key,
    required this.label,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String label;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 5, 5, 5),
          fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
        ),
        enabledBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 3,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
        ),
        focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 3, color: Color(0xffff4848)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(40)),
        ),
        errorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(
            width: 3,
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 66, 125, 145),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And then you use it like this:

```
_CustomTextField(label: 'Label 1')
SizedBox(height: 12)
_CustomTextField(label: 'Label 2')
SizedBox(height: 12)
...
```

You can even try to add the `SizedBox` inside the `_CustomTextField`!

Answer (score 0):

wrap every `TextField` widget with a `Container` widget, and specify the margins and padding you want like this :

```
  Container(
     margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0), // 10 vertical margin
      TextField(
       decoration: InputDecoration(
         labelText: '  Taille de colis',
         labelStyle: TextStyle
         color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
         fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
          ),
         enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
         borderSide: BorderSide(
         width: 3,
         color: Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 136, 136)),
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
         Radius.circular(40),
          ),),),
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want inside padding in **TextField** then you can use **"contentpadding"** inside `InputDecoratation(contentPadding : EdgeInseta.all(6))`

```
TextField(
 textAlign: TextAlign.left,
 decoration: InputDecoration(
   hintText: 'Enter Something',
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
 ),
)
```

2. And you want around of **TextField**  or  **TextFormField**  then you can Wrap with Padding Widget example.

```
Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextFormField(
           autofocus: false,
            enableSuggestions: true,
            autocorrect: true,
            style: const TextStyle(
               fontFamily: fontFamilySourceSansPro, color: black, fontSize: 16),
           validator: validateCustomerAddress,
           controller: _cusAdd2,
            focusNode: _nodeCusAdd2,
            autovalidateMode: autoValidateMode,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.streetAddress,
           textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            decoration: getTextFieldBorderLightGrayDecoration("Address 2*"),
          ),
        );
```